# Is it OK to write Javascript code to solve a browsers compatibility issue?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

Is it OK to write Javascript code to solve a browsers compatibility problem or I should never need that and everything should be solved using CSS only?

---

**My problem**:

I have a menu in an ASP.Net application, this menu renders a hidden image control supposing that `height=0` and `width=0` will not render anything. That's true in IE but it keeps an empty area in Chrome and it looks ugly.

This is the generated code:

```
<img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/WebResource.axd?d=6z..." 
     width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

I wrote the following code to solve the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('img[height="0"]').css('display', 'none');
</script>
```

Is what I did true and the only way to solve such problems?

**Note**: The code in my example is ***generated*** for an ASP.Net menu control and I have no access on it to set a specific style

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put: `style="border-width:0px; display:none;"`?

Comment: @Curt: It's code generated from ASP.Net, so, I have no access on it.

Comment: have you checked any other browsers apart from Chrome and IE? And what version(s) of IE are you testing? You may get significant differences between IE7, IE8 and IE9, let alone cross-browser.

Comment: @Spudley: It shows the same result in IE9 and IE8 and they are enough for my case. And the problem doesn't exist on FireFox.

Comment: have you looked at Chrome's dev tools, to see what is causing the unwanted area? Could it have some default padding or margin, etc? Also, using the `height` and `width` attributes is deprecated in favour of setting them via CSS.

Comment: @ Spudley: Actually I found the problem using the Chrome dev tools, it shows this area and when I select it I found the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think javascript is nessessary in this case as you can either add a class or id to the element and set a style or use:

```
img[height="0"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using javascript to change a CSS style property.

Why not simply use it like this: `style="border-width:0px; display:none;"` ?

**[Edit]**

If you really have no access to how the code is generated, you might try adding a style for the specific `img` element withing your menu `div`: `.parentClass img { display:none; }`.

It's a bit strange if there is no possibility to define css classes for any of these elements.

Comment: Because it's a generated code from ASP.Net and I have no access on it to do that.

Comment: @Homam: isn't there a CSS style applied to the `<img>` element, or the surrounding `<div>`? Can you post the code used to render the element (server side)?